# Why ContentView Width automatically change and scroll Horizontal in iOS(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, scrollview

I am new to iOS and Xamarin. I have Created `ScrollView` and it scroll on Both `Horizontal` and `Vertical`. But I want only `Vertical` scroll. Let me explain in Brief.

This is my Views hierarchy:

```
View
    -> ScrollView
        -> ContainerView
          -> UILabel
```

I am making Universal App So I choose `Generic` device. `width = 600` and `Height = 600`.

My ScrollView Constraint I set this way.

```
Top Space to SuperView : 0
Trailing Space to SuperView : 0
Leading Space to SuperView : 0
Bottom Space to SuperView : 0
```

and ContentView Constraint are below

```
Top Space to ScrollView : 0
Trailing Space to ScrollView : 0
Leading Space to ScrollView : 0
Bottom Space to SuperView : 30
```

and I also set `Frame` inside `ViewDidLayoutSubViews` method.

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            scrollView.ContentSize = addressContentView.Frame.Size;
            scrollView.LayoutIfNeeded();


        }
```

after Setting Upper thing why my `ScrollView` is taking `Horizontal` scroll. as I set `ContentView` width equals to `ScrollView`.

Any Help be Appreciated. And if you require more detail than i can give you.

Comment: are you using storyboard ?

Comment: Yes I have Create `ViewController` in StoryBoard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Spending 1 Hour finally I get Solution I change my Constraint to below and it work with only `Vertical` scroll as I wanted.

**ScrollView Constraint :**

```
Top Space to SuperView : 0
Trailing Space to SuperView : 0
Leading Space to SuperView : 0
Bottom Space to SuperView : 0
```

and **ContentView Constraint  :**

```
Top space to ScrollView : 0
Leading space to ScrollView : 0
Trailing space to Scrollview : 0
Width = scrollView.width = contentView.width
```